# PostGIS: Finding duplicate label within a radius

Tags: gis, postgis

I have data in PostGIS that have value and geometry. If there is a same value within let say <10 m, I wanna detect or remove that value from my table. Here is the small example:

```
create table points (id serial primary key, val integer, label2);

select addGeometryColumn('points', 'geom', 1, 'point', 2);

insert into points (id, val, label2, geom) values
  (1, 1, aaa, st_geomFromText('POINT(1 1)', 1)),
  (2, 1, bbb, st_geomFromText('POINT(1 2)', 1)),
  (3, 1, aaa, st_geomFromText('POINT(10 100)', 1)),
  (4, 2, ccc, st_geomFromText('POINT(10 101)', 1));
```

because of data(id) 1 and 2 has the same value and distance<10m, so there just will be:

```
  id |val| source | geom 
-----+------------+------
   3 | 1 |  aaa   | xxx
   4 | 2 |  ccc   | xxx
```

Do you know how to query that in PostGIS?

Comment: This may be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58547751/is-it-possible-to-add-a-constraint-to-a-postgres-table-using-rounded-values-for/58550936#58550936

Comment: I'm not sure. I still don't get the point and can't find the answer yet

Comment: @Anonymous which reference system are you using? you mean 10 meters or 10 miles?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean 10 meters (or it can be replace later with desired distance or radius)

Comment: @Anonymous, which reference system are you using? WGS84? In case multiple points are inside the same radius, which is the criteria to remove the superfluous points?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would consider what are the real requirements? E.g. consider points on a line with 8 meter distance: A, B, C and equal value. Do you want that to be reduced to A and C, or B? Both eliminate duplicates within 10 meters, but the result is different. What about A, B, C, D - would you like result to be A, C, or B, D, or A, D, or maybe B, C? Defining specific criteria is not trivial, and sometimes is hard to implement in SQL.

Or maybe you don't care, and just want to reduce point density? Then it is simpler, just compute `snapped = ST_SnapToGrid` with appropriate grid size, and group by  equal values of `snapped, value` and chose arbitrary point from each group. Note that this does not guarantee there are no close points (points with similar coordinates can snap to different grid cells) but it does reduce most duplicates and it is very cheap computationally.